# Como retornar o item selecionado de um spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinners

Como passar para uma variável o valor selecionado em um spineer no momento em que o usuário seleciona alguma das opções?

[Tentei implementar esta opção](https://www.android-examples.com/get-selected-item-position-of-spinner-in-android/), mas não tive sucesso.

Segue meu código caso alguém possa me dizer onde está o erro:

```
public class desafio extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText campo1, campo2;
    int pos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_desafio);

        String[] operacoes = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};

        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_operacoes);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, operacoes);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);

        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {

                pos = spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
                //teste
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso alguém esteja passando pelo mesmo problema, eu resolvi da seguinte forma:

Ao invés de `int` com a posição retornei o valor da posição para uma `string`. E a lista que popula meu spinner teve de ser declarada como `final` para que não dê problemas de uma classe interna chamando a mesma variável.

Após essas breves alterações funcionou como o esperado:

```
public class desafio extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText campo1, campo2;
String selected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_desafio);

    final String[] operacoes = {"", "+", "-", "*", "/"};
    Spinner spin = findViewById(R.id.spinner_operacoes);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, operacoes);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(adapter);

    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {

            selected = operacoes[position];
            //teste
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```